# AngularJS ng-click not being fired from dynamic buttons in JQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

in jquery code I am trying to add a function in scope and then call that function from a dyncamically created button but ng-click is not being called:

```
$(document).on("click", ".inlinelbl", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var self = this;
    var localScope = angular.element(self).scope();

        if (localScope.InlineSave_Click == undefined) {
            localScope.InlineSave_Click = function (elem, event) {
               //function body
            }
        }

        if (localScope.InlineCancel_Click == undefined) {
            localScope.InlineCancel_Click = function (elem, event) {
                //function body
        }


    var html = "<span class='d'><button class='btn btn-default' ng-click='InlineSave_Click(this, event)' style='display:inline-block;'></button>";
    html += "<button class='btn btn-default' ng-click='InlineCancel_Click()'  style='display:inline-block;'></button></span>";

    var injector = angular.element(document.getElementById('app')).injector();
    var $compile = injector.get('$compile');
    var compiledHtml = $compile(html)(localScope);

    $this.closest("span.s-element").removeClass("hide");
    $this.closest("span.s-element").append($(compiledHtml[0].outerHTML));
}
```

});

Using chrome's extension for angularjs I have checked that localscope attached with the buttons has both the functions.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: Try changing the last line to `$this.closest("span.s-element").append(compiledHtml);`. Getting the HTML back out of the result of the compile sort of defeats the purpose of compiling it. You also might need to call `localScope.$apply()` afterwards.

Comment: it did the trick. please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of taking the HTML from compiled output in this line,

```
$this.closest("span.s-element").append($(compiledHtml[0].outerHTML));
```

Append the compiled output as-is...

```
$this.closest("span.s-element").append(compiledHtml);
```

You may need to call `localScope.$apply()` afterwards.